# Fatal Error: ilInitialisation::initClientIniFile called without CLIENT_ID

Tags: installation, ubuntu-10.04, lamp, content-management

I am installing Ilias 4.1.4 is the lastest stable version on a Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit server with all the dependencies satisfied. http://www.ilias.de/docu/
Download ilias-4.1.4.zip and install Now just when all the steps are done I log out since now the installation has finished immediately upon logging out I am at following URL (the installation has just finished)

http://192.168.1.4/ilias/index.php and I get following error

```
Fatal Error: ilInitialisation::initClientIniFile called without CLIENT_ID.
```

I start searching net for above error  and do not get any useful information.After some time  I press back button and accidentally reached

```
http://192.168.1.4/ilias/setup/setup.php?cmd=logout

and see some sort of screen that asks for a client ID.
```

how can I get rid of this error
`Fatal Error: ilInitialisation::initClientIniFile called without CLIENT_ID.`
Let me know if some one here can help me to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that "CLIENT ID" refers to a database client.

On the setup screen (http://localhost/ilias/setup/setup.php) login using your root ILIAS password.  Then select "List of Clients" on the left side.  Then select "Create new Client..." and create a new database client for the ILIAS LMS.

Comment: Well I had posted the question in Feb I see you answered it in Sep,  I am out of the project now any how thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem.

Somehow if the ILIAS home page is called, the `ilias.ini.php` file should be read, and with no further client_id parameter given, give the login page for the client_id defined in clients/default in this configuration file.

However, this does not happen. Without having the time for further investigation, here the steps I've taken:

1. I renamed the `index.php` to `index_CLIENT_ID.php` where **CLIENT_ID** is the default client id.
2. I created a new `index.php` (actually a `index.html`) that forwards to `/?client_id=CLIENT_ID`, passing a parameter that then used by the ILIAS system.

Not the way it meant to be, but simple and working. Hope it helps for somebowith the very same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem (SOLVED).

But, in my "ilias.ini.php" was not set any "default client"!!!

When I write the name of my client in the row **default=""**, I solved this issue.

Stefano